# Keep values until the first record

Tags: r

Using this example:

```
dframe1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), name = c("Google", 
"Yahoo", "Amazon", "Amazon", "Google"), date = c("2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-04", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

dframe2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), date = c("2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", 
"2008-11-04", "2008-10-31", "2008-10-31", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", 
"2008-11-02", "2008-11-05", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03", "2008-10-31", 
"2008-11-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-02", "2008-11-03"
), text_sth = c("test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "another one", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"other", "etc", "test", "text_sth", "text here", "another text", 
"text here")), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)

dframe1 <- mutate(dframe1, date = as.Date(date))
dframe2 <- mutate(dframe2, date = as.Date(date))

df2 <- 
  dframe2 %>% 
  group_by(id, date) %>% 
  summarise(text_sth = paste(text_sth, collapse = " "))

left_join(dframe1, df2, by = "id") %>% 
  mutate(date_diff = as.numeric(date.y - date.x)) %>%
  filter(abs(date_diff) == 1) %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(date_diff == -1, "before", "after")) %>% 
  select(id, name, label, text_sth)
```

It is possible to keep data before and after specific time for specific date range.

How is it possible to modify it and keep data before the date based on the specific time from dframe1?

Comment: You're filtering based on columns that aren't in the data frame. There should be one conditional statement per row, and if df2 and dframe1 aren't the same length, that won't be the case

Comment: What should your desired end result look like? Can you edit your question and provide info on what the final outcome would look like for your example data?